# Can anyone explain a certain step for this change of basis problem?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Can anyone explain to me the step in the red rectangle?

Why is $1 + 2x + x^2$ put inside brackets and denoted with a $\gamma$? Then why is the right hand side set as that? What is this equation saying and what do the components mean?

Answer (score 0):

$1+2x+x^2$ is denoted with gamma means, we are going to express this vector $1+2x+x^2$ as a linear combination of elements of vectors in Gamma.

This equation is just telling Transformation of elements in basis beta in terms of elements of basis Gamma.